# Information Required

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

1. In Snowflake, table views are appearing read-only. We are unable to perform basic excel like actions i.e. add new row / columns in a table OR sort etc. Is it a feature or we are missing out something?
2. Microsoft PowerApps doesn’t have Snowflake as their available DATA CONNECTORS. May I know the timeframe in which it will be available?

Comment: Hi - for point 1, when you say "table views" do you mean tables or views?

Comment: Basically VIEWS

Comment: @FatimaAdeel - your question is actually two very different questions.  In the future, please consider asking each one separately to help focus the answers.  People tend to ignore vague and/or complex questions.

Comment: If Snowflake has an API, you can create a PowerApps [Custom Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/) to interface. This will trigger premium licensing for all users of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are, by definition, read-only (they are basically just a saved SELECT statement). If you want to change the data/columns that they display you need to change the tables that the View references and/or change the View definition.

No idea when PowerApps will have a Snowflake connector. You would need to ask Microsoft and unless it was imminent (or on a published roadmap) I doubt they would tell you